# Is there a way to call array prototype methods on union types?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, union-types

Consider following code as example:

```
    class Something {

      public getItems(): string | string[] {

        return items;
      }

    }
```

Is it Possible to access to the array prototype method on calling `getItems()` ?

Something like this ?

```
let something = new Something();

const items = something.getItems();

items.filter(i => i.length > 2); // here for example
```

Comment: Not safely, since you specify that the method may return *either* a string *or* an array. So in 50% of cases a naïve array method access would cause an error. You'd need to narrow the type down to an array first *somewhere*.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's strongly possible to narrow the type, especially if it's a defition from a library or a peace of code i'm not be able to affect or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only issue why you cant is the type `getItems` returns and it is `string | string[]`. The `string` part is a problem, as string has no Array prototype. In order to use the value returned by `getItems` we need to narrow the type by type guard.

```
const items = something.getItems(); // items is string | string[]

if (typeof items !== 'string') {
  // now type is narrowed to string[]
  items.filter(i => i.length > 2); // fully type safe
} else {
  // here you have a string
}
```

We can also do that more consist by narrowing the structure to the array of strings also for `string`.

```
const items = something.getItems(); // items is string | string[]
// in line below I am bringing both possible values into array structure
const finalItems = typeof items === 'string' ? [items] : items; 
finalItems.filter(i => i.length > 2); // fully type safe
```

The important in above is `[items]` where I put single string value into array, thanks that `finalItems` has only one type - `string[]`

Comment: This is the only meaningful answer. Type guards are very powerful ([more info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types))

Answer (score 1):

`concat` can take arguments of either type: string or array of string. In either case, it gives the same result (an array):

```
let filtered = [].concat(items).filter(i => i.length > 2);
```

I would however advise to adjust the interface of `Something` so that it already takes care of this, and only returns arrays, even if only having one string.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but only one thing that you have to consider. `getItems()` method returns array or string. If it returns a string, your application will throw an error that is `cannot read property of undefined`. To prevent this, your method should always return an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
let something = new Something();
const items: any = something.getItems();
items.filter(i => i.length > 2);
```

- In this case, compilation error will be supressed.
- But for the code to work at runtime, the returning value should be an string[].
- If not **TypeError: items.filter is not a function** will be thrown.